# Configuring HSRP on multiple L3 devices

Tags: layer3, hsrp

I am currently doing an enterprise campus network which consist of Three Tier hierarchy and a simple MPLS design.

Currently, I'm stucked at HSRP configuration on the Core Layer to the Edge Router. Core Layer has 2 interfaces connected to the Edge Router. However, in order to do HSRP, both sides have to be in L3 and in the same subnet as well.

[image]

Core E4/2 and E4/3 is connected to CE1 and CE2. How do i assign IP addresses in the same subnet for the Core interfaces so as to allow HSRP to work?

Comment: Why do you need HSRP? They’re all routers , right?

Comment: In the event if any router goes down, the backup router will kick in to provide default gateway redundancies

Comment: That is what routing protocols do, much faster than HSRP.

Answer (score 2):

> Currently, I'm stucked at HSRP configuration on the Core Layer to the
> Edge Router. Core Layer has 2 interfaces connected to the Edge Router.

Layer-3 switches are routers too. You do not run HSRP between the routers. You should have different layer-3 routed links in different networks. You run a routing protocol, e.g. OSPF, and it will know when a link goes down and move to the backup. A routing protocol is much, much faster than HSRP to fail over.